# issue with printing the elements of an array in django?

Tags: python, django, arrays, templates

I have an array which prints the list of some elements. I want to print those elements in a group of say '4'. That is if our array has 10 elements. Then in my template first `<div>` shows  first 4 elements and next `<div>` shows next 4 elements. and so on.

I have tried to print like as we prints in PHP but it does not work here so please suggest me some way to do that.

There are 9 products in c.list and i want to show them as i have mentioned above:

```
{% if c.list|length >= 1 or c.list|length < 5 %}
        {% for p in c.list %}

        <div class="dis_box1">

        <div class="item_imagebox_01"><a href="/shop/product/{{p.title}}"><img style ="width:145px;height:190px;"alt="" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{p.image}}"></a>
        <div class="img_line1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="left"><span class="heart_text1"><a href="/shop/product/jhgjgj/">{{p.title}}</a></span></div>

            </div> 

        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can we see the code you have tried? Your question is hard to interpret. I assume you want the `if` and `for` tags that you nest inside of templates?

Comment: I have edited my question please look at that

Comment: Can you try `{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}</div><div>{% endif %}`

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to split the list up into groups of four in your views code, and then pass that through so the template has to do less work.

Comment: That's what i am asking how to split the lists..I am using  c.list[3] to show 3rd product of the array..but it throughs error..

Comment: In view you can split list into chunks using: `[l[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(l),4)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of work you should really be doing in your view.

In your view:

```
list_by_fours = []
list_len = len(c.list)
last_point = 0
next_point = 4

while last_point < list_len:
  if next_point > list_len:
    next_point = list_len
  list_by_fours.append(c.list[last_point:next_point])
  last_point += 4
  next_point += 4

#Make sure you add list_by_fours to the template context
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for bucket in list_by_fours %}
        {% for p in bucket %}
             ...
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this with itertools or some other fancy trick, but this is clean and easy to understand for beginners.